# French term for Overcompleteness

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-french

I am looking for the French term for the notion of [overcompleteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overcompleteness) in linear algebra. The current suggestion I have is "sursaturée", but I couldn't find the term in literature.

P.S. I am not french, so please excuse my poor survey of french math literature.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the term is "surcomplétude". The following papers make use of this term:

[Interactions entre l’analyse complexe et
la théorie des opérateurs](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/%7Efricain/hdr-fricain.pdf)

[Propriétés géométriques des suites de noyaux reproduisants
dans les espaces modèles](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/%7Efricain/versionpreliminaire.pdf)

Comment: In these references, the term is used in the context of sequences? Is the term same in linear algebra too?

Comment: @kksagar I believe so; however, I cannot tell for certain.